# не работает GetComponent<>()

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Вызываю GetComponent и пытаюсь получить значение из определенного скрипта
когда рейкаст касается ресурса то пытается получить его значение айди из класса Resource

вот код рейкаста

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = new Ray(camera.transform.position, camera.transform.forward);
            Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);
            Debug.DrawRay(camera.transform.position, camera.transform.forward);

            if(hit.collider)
            {
                hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Resource>().Loot();
            }
        }
```

вот код ресурса

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Resource : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int ID;

    public void Loot()
    {
        Debug.Log("ДОБЫЛ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Воспользуйся отладкой. Посмотри, в условие вообще входит ли.

Comment: `GetComponent<>()` работает! Это ты сам решил, что если луч во что-то попал то это 1000% `Resource` и никак иначе? А у объекта с компонентом `Resource` вообще есть коллайдер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том что:

- Сценарий называется не `Resource`

  или
- Вы не присоединили его к коллайдеру объекта

также лучше присоединить сценарий не к коллайдеру, а к самому объекту, тогда нужен вот такой код:

```cs
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = new Ray(camera.transform.position, camera.transform.forward);
            Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);
            Debug.DrawRay(camera.transform.position, camera.transform.forward);
            Resource behaviour = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Resource>();
            if (behaviour != null) {
                behaviour.Loot();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Сделал, теперь ошибки нет, но и дебаг сообщение не выводится

Comment: а нет, все работает! спасибо!